# Spock does not work for an expected "matched invocations" working through @WebAppConfiguration

Tags: spock, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am working with

- STS
- Gradle
- Spock Core
- Spock Reports
- Spock Spring
- Spring MVC Testing

I have the following test code:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes=[RootApplicationContextConfig.class,ServletApplicationContextConfig.class])
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
class PersonaXmlFindOneControllerTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private PersonaXmlFindOneController personaXmlFindOneController 

    def setup(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

        personaXmlFindOneController = webApplicationContext.getBean(PersonaXmlFindOneController.class);

        println personaXmlFindOneController.toString()

    }

    def "findOneRequestParamById deberia ser llamado"(){

        String url = null
        ResultActions resultActions = null

        given: "The URL being used "

           url = "some url to test"

        when: "When the URL is being calling with a GET"

            resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get(url, PersonaControllerSupport.ID)).andDo(print())

        then: "...."

            resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk())
                         .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
                         .andExpect(xpath("persona").exists())
                         .andExpect(xpath("persona").nodeCount(1))
….

        //then: 

            //1 * personaXmlFindOneController.findOneRequestParamById(_ as String)           

    }
```

The code works fine. It pass.

**Furthemore**: through Gradle Test Report thanks to **andDo(print())** I can confirm that personaXmlFindOneController.findOneRequestParamById has been called.

It means

```
Handler:

Type = com.manuel.jordan.controller.xml.PersonaXmlFindOneController
Method = public com.manuel.jordan.domain.xml.PersonaXml com.manuel.jordan.controller.xml.PersonaXmlFindOneController.findOneRequestParamById(java.lang.String)
```

Now If enable

```
//then: 
    //1 * personaXmlFindOneController.findOneRequestParamById(_ as String)
```

The code fails,

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * personaXmlFindOneController.findOneRequestParamById(_ as String)   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None
```

Observe that in the setup method, it has been retrieved through

```
personaXmlFindOneController = webApplicationContext.getBean(PersonaXmlFindOneController.class);
```

Therefore, what is missing or what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two different mocking mechanisms.

There is the Spring one (MockMVC) and the Spock one.

Spock can only verify mocks created by itself (.i.e those created with the Spock Mock() method). You don't create any Spock mocks in your code and therefore Spock mocking will not work.

See the official documentation of Spock for the full mocking guide to understand how you can create mocks with Spock only.

In your particular example your original code is correct and it should stay that way. You don't always have to use the Spock mocking mechanism. Having a Spock test that uses only Spring testing facilities is perfectly fine.

Comment: Has sense your answer, let me confirm this through a Spring JIRA issue. Thanks